# Задача на персистентную структуру данных

Tags: алгоритм, оптимизация, структуры-данных

Есть `n` массивов `(n <= 10^5)`, `k` запросов `(k <= 10^5)`.

Каждый запрос - это одно из двух действий:

- объединить два массива
- разделить массив на два новых (нацело поделить размер исходного)

Каждое действие порождает новый(-ые) массивы, для каждого нового массива необходимо выводить произведение всех элементов по модулю количества элементов в этом массиве. - `(a1*a2*...*am)%m`, где m - количество элементов в массиве.

Ограничения: по времени `2 секунды`, по памяти `256 МБ`.

Данная задача, безусловно, решается с помощью какой-либо персистентной структуры данных. Я попробовать решить с помощью персистентного декартово дерева (Treap, дерамида, называйте как хотите).

В структуре Node я добавил 2 новых поля: размер и ответ на запрос (модуль произведений). В итоге Node у меня весит 40 байт. Задача не проходит по памяти, примерно на 100-200мб :)

Скажите, возможно ли оптимизировать это решение, либо использовать другую структуру данных, если да то, то подскажите какую.

Comment: вы можете уточнить - `n` ("Есть `n` массивов") - это количество массивов или число элементов в одном массиве (`a1*a2*...*an)%n`)?

Comment: @MaxU, спасибо, исправил